# Get column and row number of the selected cell of a Flexigrid

Tags: javascript, flexigrid

I'm currently using a Flexigrid and I would like to recover the column number and also the row number of the selected cell.

I managed to recover the content of the selected one by adding "*process: procMe*" in the column model and by writing the following function :

```
function procMe(celDiv, id){
    $(celDiv).click(function(){
        var content = this.innerHTML;
    }
}
```

But I didn't find yet how to get the column and row numbers.

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 0):

`celDiv` is the div inside the table cell.
Firstly, get the table cell:

```
var td = $(celDiv).closest('td');
```

Now, we use jQuery's [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method to get the relative position of that td within it's siblings

```
var colIndex = td.index();
```

`colIndex` should now contain the zero-based column index of that cell/header cell.
You should be able to do something similar with the row by retrieving the row, and then getting its index within its siblings:

```
var tr = td.closest('tr');
var rowIndex = td.index();
```